# Why does the login box appear without the link being clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a login box modal dialog window with CSS, HTML and jQuery but the login box is appearing without me clicking the Login / Sign In link. My HTML code is fairly straightforward:

```
<a href="#login-box" class="login-window">Login / Sign In</a>


<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
<a href="#" class="close"><img src="close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>
  <form method="post" class="signin" action="#">
        <fieldset class="textbox">
        <label class="username">
        <span>Username or email</span>
        <input id="username" name="username" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Username">
        </label>
        <label class="password">
        <span>Password</span>
        <input id="password" name="password" value="" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </label>
        <button class="submit button" type="button">Sign in</button>
        <p>
        <a class="forgot" href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
        </p>        
        </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css" />
```

The CSS is more complex:

```
#mask {
    display: none;
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 999;
}

#login-popup {
    display: none;
    background: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 99999;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
    /* CSS3 */
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
    /* Firefox */
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
    /* Safari, Chrome */
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    /* Firefox */
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    /* Safari, Chrome */;
}

img#btn_close {
    Position the close button
    float: right;
    margin: -28px -28px 0 0;
}

fieldset {
    border: none;
}

form#signin #textbox label {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}

form#signin #textbox span {
    display: block;
}

form#signin p, form#signin span {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

form#signin #textbox input {
    background: #666666;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 6px 6px 4px;
    width: 200px;
}

form#signin input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #bbb;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
}

form#signin input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #bbb;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
}

#button {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #f3f3f3, #dddddd);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f3f3f3), to(#dddddd));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f3f3f3, #dddddd);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#f3f3f3', EndColorStr='#dddddd');
    border-color: #000;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 6px 4px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font: 12px;
    width: 214px;
}

#button:hover {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

The jQuery is new to me and there is most likely a few errors in there.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.login-window').click(function() {

    var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

    //Fade in the Popup
    $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

    //Set the center alignment padding + border see css style
    var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

    $(loginBox).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    // Add the mask to body
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

    return false;
});

// When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
$('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
  $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
    $('#mask').remove();  
}); 
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Does anyone see some errors in that code that could be causing the problem? If so please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with HTML

```
<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
```

and CSS

```
#login-popup {
    display: none;
```

You use the `#` in the css selector which is for ids but the element has a class..

So the CSS rule should use `.`

```
.login-popup {
        display: none;
```

Same error seems to exist for all your rules.. you use classes in the HTML but try to target them with id selectors in CSS

Comment: Thank you, but what's the problem with the <div id="login-box" class="login-popup"> HTML code?

Comment: no problem on that line alone (*only in relation to the css that is targeting that line*)

Comment: Okay. But now when I click the Login / Sign In link the box doesn't appear.

Comment: @user3058895, have you included jQuery ? and if yes, what version ?

Comment: Strange. It works perfectly fine in JSFiddle but when I open the document in a browser it doesn't work. I've tried opening it in several browsers but it hasn't worked in any.

Comment: can you post a link to your page ?

Comment: Sure: file:///C:/Users/Beth/Documents/login.html. Sorry for the poor design of the site but I'm barely half way through designing the site remember.

Comment: I thought you had that file live (*we can't have access to your pc - and for good reason*).. anyway upon reviewing your code, i see that your code is in the same `script` tag as the jquery inclusion.. you cannot do that. `script` tags can either have an `src` attribute to load a file ***or*** have inline code.. so you need to close the script tag for the jquery library and add a new one for your own code..